# What is the equal control for FederatedPassiveSignInStatus control in .net 4.5?

Tags: single-sign-on, wif, federated-identity, sts-securitytokenservice

I have written an STS (security token service) for single sign-on. But i have used .net 4 and the Microsoft.IdentityModel and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Controls. 
Now i wanna convert my code to .net 4.5 but there is no namespace for handling the "FederatedPassiveSignInStatus" control. What should do and what is the solution for this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) has been fully integrated into the .NET Framework. The version of WIF addressed by this topic, WIF 3.5, is deprecated and should only be used when developing against the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 or the .NET Framework 4. For more information about WIF in the .NET Framework 4.5, also known as WIF 4.5, see the [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377151.aspx) documentation in the .NET Framework 4.5 Development Guide.]

Comment: I know this issue but what is the equal for FederatedPassiveSignInStatus control in .net 4.5?

Comment: In page:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157091.aspx. As it said, this method has been discarded:"The classes in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.Controls implemented the Federated Passive Sign-In Control, which does not exist in WIF 4.5." But this page may help you :http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e10b43a6-c9d3-430b-a02c-8ac8f94136fa/how-to-sign-out-in-wif-45-now-federatedpassivesigninstatus-control-has-gone?forum=Geneva

Comment: System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut

Comment: Do you know, how can i sign in without using "FederatedPassiveSignIn" control?